# Create custom header with LaTeX

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[headheight=55pt]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
 \fancyhead[L]{
     \begin{tabular}{ll}
         \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{logo1}%
         \end{tabular} &

          \begin{tabular}[b]{l}
                Latex World Learning  \tabularnewline
                very neat\tabularnewline
                no irritating eyes\tabularnewline
            \end{tabular} 

            \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{logo2}%
            \end{tabular} &

     \end{tabular}
    }%
  }

  \pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

I tried to create customized header with LaTeX editor, above the current code and sample header below....

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your example does not compile because the `logo` files are not available to us. Also I don't understand your question really

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing ... Are you trying to do something like this?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[headheight=55pt]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{m{2cm}Xm{5cm}Xm{2cm}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} & &
\centering
Latex World Learning\newline 
very neat\newline
no irritating eyes\newline & &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}\\
\end{tabularx}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Or simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[headheight=55pt]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{%
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} \hfill 
\parbox[b]{5cm}{\centering Latex World Learning\\
very neat\\ no irritating eyes} \hfill 
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```